# function not returning a value to be used in main

Tags: python

My code is a follows:

```
def main():
    convert("time")
    print(float_time)


def convert(time):
    time = input("What time is it? ")
    if len(time) > 4:
        sliced_hour = slice(2)
        sliced_minutes = slice(3, 5)
        hour = time[sliced_hour]
        minutes = time[sliced_minutes]

    else:
        sliced_hour = slice(1)
        sliced_minutes = slice(2,4)
        hour = time[sliced_hour]
        minutes = time[sliced_minutes]

    minutes_int = int(minutes)
    hour_int = int(hour)

    minutes_float = ( minutes_int / 60)
    float_time = float(hour_int + minutes_float)
    return float_time`


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am a complete beginner my code is most likely sub-optimal. Having said that, why is my function not returning the value of float_time to be used in main?

I have tried researching the return function as well as changing float_time to a str etc

Comment: the "`" at the end of "return float_time" is not in my actual code...

Comment: You need to assign the return value of the function to a variable, for example `float_time = convert("time")`. This doesn't have to be the same name as the variable inside the function, of course.

Comment: or just `print(convert("time")`. Essentially `float_time` variable in main has no value. the value of `float_time` inside of the `convert()` function only exists inside in the `convert()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are local to functions (they can be  "global" but they have to explicitly be declared as so) -
Your function runs as expected (likely, I did not check it), but the single value it will return to the caller (`main`) is the expression after the `return` statement ( float_time ): functions return the *result* of the expression, not by making that variable avaliable in the caller.

It is up to the caller to assign the return value(s) of a function to the desired variable in the context they will be used.

That said, all you need to do (to get the return value - again: I did not check your function's code):

```
def main():
    float_time = convert("time")
    print(float_time)
```

This will create a new, independent "float_time" variable (which, btw, could have any other name) that will be assigned the return value of the called function.

Answer (score 0):

`float_time` is local to the `convert` function, so `main` has no idea what its value is. That is, `float_time` only exists inside `convert`!

Instead, you should store the *result* of calling `convert()`, and then `print` that.

Also, calling `convert("time")` using `"time"` as an argument is erroneous, but it's not breaking anything as-written because the `time` parameter is immediately overwritten by `time = input("What time is it? ")` - really, `convert` doesn't need any arguments since the information is coming from the user via `input()`

```
def main():
    result = convert()  # store the value returned by 'convert' in a variable
    print(result)  # print that value


def convert():  # no parameters needed here
    time = input("What time is it? ")
    if len(time) > 4:
        sliced_hour = slice(2)
        sliced_minutes = slice(3, 5)
        hour = time[sliced_hour]
        minutes = time[sliced_minutes]

    else:
        sliced_hour = slice(1)
        sliced_minutes = slice(2,4)
        hour = time[sliced_hour]
        minutes = time[sliced_minutes]

    minutes_int = int(minutes)
    hour_int = int(hour)

    minutes_float = ( minutes_int / 60)
    float_time = float(hour_int + minutes_float)
    return float_time


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

FWIW: You could also skip the variable assignment in `main` and just use this instead

```
def main()
    print(convert())
```

since you aren't doing anything else with the return value as-written!